# загрузить изображения заранее

Tags: javascript

Как можно заранее загрузить несколько изображений, чтобы во время их появления не было белого квадрата?

Comment: Добавьте `display: none` к элементу, и после загрузки изменяйте его.

Comment: Создайте прелоадер

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать `link prefetching` из HTML5

```
<link rel="prefetch" href="image.png">
```

Например:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="prefetch" href="https://images/img.png">
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://images/img.png">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Лучше использовать `preload` - у `prefetch` есть проблемы

Answer (score -1):

Предзагрузка картинок на JavaScript (JQuery)

Вариант с загрузкой на JS, как мне кажется, один из самых лучший, особенно если вы имеете дело с анимацией. Его суть в том, что вы просто посредством JavaScript создаете копию картинки и загружаете её в буфер браузера, тем самым при необходимости уже не нужно будет подгружать картинку, так как она уже будет предварительно загружена.
*Не люблю я  JQ* но что бы было всем проще можно вот таким кодом, где нужно заменить путь к картинке на свой и все будет работать:

```
//создаем JQuery функцию, которая будет подгружать изображения в буфер
jQuery.preloadImages = function()
 {
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
  {
   jQuery("<img>").attr("src", arguments[ i ]);
  }
 };

//указываем путь к изображению, которое нужно подгрузить
$.preloadImages("/tpl/testimg.png");
```

Если же вам нужно подгрузить несколько изображений, то вы просто можете перечислить их через запятую, вот так:

```
$.preloadImages("imageone.jpg", "dirname/imageok.jpg", "/tpl/testimg.png");
```

Картинок может быть любое количество.

> Главное не забывайте про JQuery функцию, без нее предзагрузка работать не будет.

Comment: Тоесть для начала надо ждать загрузку JQuery, а уже потом загружать изображения... Почему нельзя написать этот код на ваниле в header'e?
P.S. Знаю старый вопрос, но все же